# If $\gcd(n,a)=1$, and $\gcd(n,b)=1$ prove $\gcd(n,ab)=1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

If $\gcd(n,a)=1$, and $\gcd(n,b)=1$, prove $\gcd(n,ab)=1$

Comment: Hey. What are your own thoughts on this problem, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove this. Even my professor said that he didn't know how to.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ua+vn =1, u'b+v'n=1$. $(ua+vn)(u'b+v'n)=1 = uu'(ab)+(uav'+u'vb+vnv')n$